# What is the probability that the sum of two dice beats one?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, dice

I always seem to struggle with even the most basic probability problems. Last night, I thought up the following simple scenario:

> Alice and Bob are rolling standard (6-sided) dice. Due to gender
>   discrimination, Bob gets two dice to Alice's one. What's the probability
>   that the sum of Bob's two dice will exceed Alice's?

I have attempted to solve this (see below). However, I am wondering if my method is (i) correct and (ii) efficient. For such a simple problem, this really took me a long time.

After some reading, I figured I could start with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability):

$$\begin{eqnarray} 
P(B>A)&=&\sum_{k=1}^6 P(B>A \cap A=k) \\
&=&\sum_{k=1}^6 P(B>A | A=k)P(A=k) \\
&=&\frac{1}{6}\sum_{k=1}^6 P(B>A | A=k) \\
&=&\frac{1}{6}\sum_{k=1}^6 P(B>k)
\end{eqnarray} $$

where A is Alice's total and B is Bob's. However, even those $P(B>k)$ look like some work to calculate. If I consider Bob's two dice values separately (so $B = B_1+B_2$):

$$\begin{eqnarray} 
P(B>k)&=&\sum_{n=1}^6 P(B>k \cap B_1=n) \\
&=&\sum_{n=1}^6 P(B>k | B_1=n)P(B_1=n) \\
&=&\frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=1}^6 P(B>k | B_1=n) \\
&=&\frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=1}^6 P(B_2>k-n) \\
\end{eqnarray} $$

Working these out by hand, I get:
$$\begin{eqnarray} 
P(B>1)&=&1 \\
P(B>2)&=&\frac{35}{36} \\
P(B>3)&=&\frac{33}{36} \\
P(B>4)&=&\frac{30}{36} \\
P(B>5)&=&\frac{26}{36} \\
P(B>6)&=&\frac{21}{36}
\end{eqnarray} $$

Adding them up and dividing by 6, I get:
$$P(B>A)=\frac{181}{216}\approx 0.83796$$

Now, I have no idea how to check if this is correct. I did a few more sums and it seems that Bob is more than **9 times** more likely to win than Alice, which I find quite surprising!

**Please note**: A similar (but more general) question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240221/probability-of-a-dice-with-x-faces-beating-b-dice-with-y-faces), but no answer was given for multiple dice. I followed the advice of one of the answers and wrote a computer program, which gave me the same result as above.
The question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3000997/probably-of-winning-with-2-dice-maximum-of-them-against-another-one/3001114#3001114) looks very similar, but I think it's actually very different.

Comment: I don't see a problem. A good tip when using the law of total probability is "condition on what you wish you knew". In this case, it would be nice if we knew what Alice has rolled. So you followed this problem solving tip nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct.  We can confirm it by complementary counting.

Suppose Bob rolls a blue die and a green die.  For $k \leq 7$, the number of ways Bob could obtain a sum of exactly $k$ is the number of solutions of the equation
$$b + g = k$$
in the positive integers, where $b$ is the number displayed by the blue die and $g$ is the number displayed by the green die.  Each solution corresponds to the placement of a single addition single addition sign in the $k - 1$ spaces between successive ones in a row of $k$ ones.  To illustrate with $k = 7$,
$$1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1$$
the outcome 
$$1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1$$ 
corresponds to $b = 3, g = 4$, while
$$1 + 1 1 1 1 1 1$$
corresponds to $b = 1, g = 6$.

The number of solutions of $b + g = k$ is $k - 1$ since there are exactly $k - 1$ places to put the addition sign.

Hence, the number of ways that Bob rolls a sum of at most $n$ is 
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{n} (k - 1) = \frac{n(n - 1)}{2}$$
Since there are $6^2 = 36$ possible outcomes, the probability that Bob rolls a sum of at most $n$ is 
$$\Pr(B \leq n) = \frac{1}{36} \cdot \frac{n(n - 1)}{2}$$

If we denote the value Alice obtains by $A$ and the sum that Bob obtains by $B$, the probability that Bob's sum is at most the value Alice obtains is
\begin{align*}
\Pr(B \leq A) & = \sum_{n = 1}^{6} \Pr(A = n)\Pr(B \leq A \mid A = n)\\
              & = \frac{1}{6}\sum_{n = 1}^{6} \Pr(B \leq A \mid A = n)\\
              & = \frac{1}{6}\left[\frac{0}{36} + \frac{1}{36} + \frac{3}{36} + \frac{6}{36} + \frac{10}{36} + \frac{15}{36}\right]\\
              & = \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\left(\frac{35}{36}\right)\\
              & = \frac{35}{216}
\end{align*}
Hence, the probability that Bob's score exceeds Alice's score is
$$\Pr(B > A) = 1 - \Pr(B \leq A) = 1 - \frac{35}{216} = \frac{181}{216}$$
as you found.

Comment: Isn't the $b+g=k$ equation valid for any $k$ between $2$ and $12$? (Not just $\leq7$).

Comment: Also, the equation for "the probability that Bob rolls a sum of at most $n$" looks more like the number of ways he can roll $n$. Then I guess we need to divide by the total number of possible rolls (36) to get probability?

Comment: Keep in mind that $b$ and $g$ represent numbers displayed on $6$-sided dice.  If we did not have that restriction, then the number of solutions of the equation $b + g = k$ in the positive integers would always be $k - 1$.  However, consider the equation $b + g = 12$.  Since the dice are six-sided, there is only one valid solution since solutions in which $b > 6$ or $g > 6$ are prohibited.  However, by symmetry, the number of solutions in the positive integers with $b + g = k$ is equal to the number of positive integers solutions with $(7 - b) + (7 - g) = 14 - k$, which we can use for $k > 7$.

Comment: In response to your second comment, thanks for pointing out the error.  You are also  correct about the way the probability is calculated.

Comment: So, does that mean that the $\Pr(B \leq n)$ equation is also only valid for $n \leq 7$, but that's sufficient because we only need $n=1,2,\dots ,6$ in the last step?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.